# --load-extension parameter for chrome doesn't work (mac)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is the command to load a single extension

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --load-extension="~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/cflchafndefoljnhhholeekfpgmbphaf/1.51_0/"`

It throws me “Failed to load extension from: . Manifest file is missing or unreadable.”.

The weird thing is if I copy the extension to /tmp/ and load from there. It works.

Comment: Same issue. Somehow related to SPACE in the extension folder string.